# C, Wav File Chunk Sizes Issue

Tags: c, wav, chunks

Given a WAV file, I'd like to print out the ChunkSize, SubChunk1Size and SubChunk2Size.

[image]

Below is the code I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct wavFile{

    char ChunkID[4]; //"RIFF", GOOD
    unsigned int ChunkSize;
    char Format[4]; //"WAVE", GOOD
    char Subchunk1ID[4]; //"fmt", GOOD
    unsigned int Subchunk1Size;  //GOOD
    unsigned short int AudioFormat; //GOOD
    unsigned short int NumChannels; //GOOD
    unsigned int SampleRate; //GOOD
    unsigned int ByteRate;
    unsigned int BlockAlign;
    unsigned int BitsPerSample;
    char SubChunk2ID[4]; //"data", prints weird symbols instead of "data"
    unsigned int Subchunk2Size;

};

int main()
{
    struct wavFile w;
    int headerSize = sizeof(w);
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(wavFilePathGoesHere, "r");
    fread(&w, headerSize, 1, fp);



    printf("ChunkSize: %d, SubChunk1Size: %d, SubChunk2Size: %d\n", w.ChunkSize, w.Subchunk1Size, w.Subchunk2Size);
    //SubChunk2Size: -76154081

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The variables that I commented in the structure as "GOOD" actually give the correct values, so those are good. The printf statement gives a negative SubChunk2Size value (-76154081). Certainly, this can't be right. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Is your structure size right? You'd better check it - and then pack it to make it work correctly.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not a 100% sure. I literally just learned about structures. I'm quite new to C.

Comment: Beware that not all architectures use little endian, so simply reading the data directly into memory like this is not portable.  Also, Carl Norum raised a valid point about packing.  Again, this is a portability thing that may not always give the same results on different compilers.  Read up on struct padding / packing if you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%u` not `%d` for your printf of unsigned ints. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ specifically

```
specifier   Output                   Example
d or i      Signed decimal integer   392
u           Unsigned decimal integer 7235
```

Comment: Right! I didn't know I need to use u for unsigned type

Comment: Please see other comments and answers about getting your structure correctly aligned to the data specification. You may have multiple problems here. But the %u vs %d will be causing you issues as well.

Answer (score 2):

`BlockAlign` and `BitsPerSample` should be shorts.

Comment: @0100100001101001 Please remember to accept the answer that fixs your problem.